# Building Docker image as non root user

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

New here, was wondering if someone had experience with building images as non root user?

I am building Kotlin project, (2 step build) and my goal is now to build it as non root user. Here is what my Dockerfile looks like. Any help would be appreciated:

```
# Build
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim as builder

# Compile application
WORKDIR /root
COPY . .
RUN ./gradlew build

FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

# Add application
COPY --from=builder /root/build/libs/*.jar ./app.jar

# Set the build version
ARG build_version
ENV BUILD_VERSION=$build_version

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod 777 /docker-entrypoint.sh
CMD /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: You don't need root for that. You have to be inside `docker` group on most systems.

Comment: And I am asking how to do something like
`RUN groupadd -r test && useradd --no-log-init -r -g test test` and use that user inside this dockerfile

Comment: A Docker container has its own filesystem space and its own `/etc/passwd` file; a user inside a container often won't match any particular host user.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to use Docker, you don't need to be a root user, you just need to be inside of the docker user group.

**On Linux:**

1. If there is not already a docker group, you can create one using the command `sudo groupadd docker`.
2. Add yourself and any other users you would like to be able to access docker to this group using the command `sudo usermod -aG docker [username of user]`.
3. Relog, so that Linux can re-evaluate user groups.

If you are not trying to run the command as root, but rather want to run the container as non-root, you can use the following `DOCKERFILE` contents (insert after `FROM` but before anything else.)

```sh
# Add a new user "john" with user id 8877
RUN useradd -u 8877 john
# Change to non-root privilege
USER john
```

Comment: Oh that second part was what I was asking for. So I just add a user like that and that's all?

Comment: Yep - that should work. All it needs to do is create a new user (in this case named `john`) and switch to this new user.

Comment: Why user id 8877? Is that an arbitrary ID or is that significant?

Comment: Pretty sure it's arbitrary. Not sure why I put that in there to be honest.

Comment: @Adil Sadik In Linux users are identified by an unique uid and username, with the -u flag set you choose a id. without the flag it will assign the next available. https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd

Comment: Please be aware of the WARNING the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) state about adding a user to the `docker` group: "**The docker group grants root-level privileges** to the user. For details on how this impacts security in your system, see [Docker Daemon Attack Surface](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface)."